# Error trying to pass list to hyperas as a parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, keras

I'm working on hyper-paramter optimization using keras and the [hyperas library](https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas).

I'm trying to pass a list instead of a hard coded list but it throws an error. In hyperas you wrap your template value in "{{ some value }}" which you can card code to be a list. Example:

```
model.add(Dense({{choice([258,512,1024])}}))
```

Error:

```
File "hy.py", line 89, in
trials=Trials())
File "/home/peachy/Documents/tensorflow/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperas-0.4-py3.6.egg/hyperas/optim.py", line 67, in minimize
verbose=verbose)
File "/home/peachy/Documents/tensorflow/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperas-0.4-py3.6.egg/hyperas/optim.py", line 118, in base_minimizer
space=get_space(),
File "/home/peachy/Documents/tensorflow/temp_model.py", line 119, in get_space
NameError: name 'dropout' is not defined
```

Using a basic example, this is the model class. I'm loading in from a yml file which loads in lists, but that doesn't work so I'm just trying to create a list in the model class and pass that in just the same. It won't work.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from hyperopt import Trials, STATUS_OK, tpe
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.utils import np_utils

from hyperas import optim
from hyperas.distributions import choice, uniform, conditional
import common_config as cfg

def data():
    """
    Data providing function:
    This function is separated from model() so that hyperopt
    won't reload data for each evaluation run.
    """
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784)
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
    x_train /= 255
    x_test /= 255
    nb_classes = 10
    y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
    y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)
    return x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test


def model(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test):
    """
    Model providing function:
    Create Keras model with double curly brackets dropped-in as needed.
    Return value has to be a valid python dictionary with two customary keys:
        - loss: Specify a numeric evaluation metric to be minimized
        - status: Just use STATUS_OK and see hyperopt documentation if not feasible
    The last one is optional, though recommended, namely:
        - model: specify the model just created so that we can later use it again.
    """
    ModelConfig = cfg.ModelConfig
    dropout = [0,1]
    print (dropout)
    print (type(dropout))




    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(784,)))
    model.add(Activation(ModelConfig.activation))
    model.add(Dropout({{uniform(dropout)}}))
    model.add(Dense({{choice([258,512,1024])}}))
    model.add(Activation({{choice(['relu', 'sigmoid'])}}))
    model.add(Dropout({{uniform(0,1)}}))

    # If we choose 'four', add an additional fourth layer
    if conditional({{choice(['three', 'four'])}}) == 'four':
        model.add(Dense(100))

        # We can also choose between complete sets of layers

        model.add({{choice([Dropout(0.5), Activation('linear')])}})
        model.add(Activation('relu'))

    model.add(Dense(10))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'],
                  optimizer={{choice(['rmsprop', 'adam', 'sgd'])}})

    model.fit(x_train, y_train,
              batch_size={{choice([64, 128])}},
              epochs=1,
              verbose=2,
              validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
    score, acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
    print('Test accuracy:', acc)
    return {'loss': -acc, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'model': model}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    best_run, best_model = optim.minimize(model=model,
                                          data=data,
                                          algo=tpe.suggest,
                                          max_evals=10,
                                          trials=Trials())
    X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test = data()
    print("Evalutation of best performing model:")
    print(best_model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test))
    print("Best performing model chosen hyper-parameters:")
    print(best_run)
```

How is the value sent from the template to the optim.py file ?
I've checked and the regular expression should be able to handle the list.

I don't expect anyone to know but how would you go about debugging this as it's a library issue most likely

EDIT

Solution 1 & 2 result in just an type error being thrown which in the source code is a very strange check to see if it's a certain string type

Hyperopt code pyll_util.py

```
def validate_label(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(label, *args, **kwargs):
        is_real_string = isinstance(label, basestring)
        is_literal_string = (isinstance(label, Literal) and
                             isinstance(label.obj, basestring))
        if not is_real_string and not is_literal_string:
            raise TypeError('require string label')
        return f(label, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hy.py", line 107, in <module>
    trials=Trials())
  File "/home/peachy/Documents/tensorflow/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperas-0.4-py3.6.egg/hyperas/optim.py", line 67, in minimize
    verbose=verbose)
  File "/home/peachy/Documents/tensorflow/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperas-0.4-py3.6.egg/hyperas/optim.py", line 136, in base_minimizer
    return_argmin=True),
  File "/home/peachy/Documents/tensorflow/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 307, in fmin
    return_argmin=return_argmin,
  File "/home/peachy/Documents/tensorflow/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/base.py", line 635, in fmin
    return_argmin=return_argmin)
  File "/home/peachy/Documents/tensorflow/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 320, in fmin
    rval.exhaust()
  File "/home/peachy/Documents/tensorflow/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 199, in exhaust
    self.run(self.max_evals - n_done, block_until_done=self.async)
  File "/home/peachy/Documents/tensorflow/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 173, in run
    self.serial_evaluate()
  File "/home/peachy/Documents/tensorflow/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 92, in serial_evaluate
    result = self.domain.evaluate(spec, ctrl)
  File "/home/peachy/Documents/tensorflow/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/base.py", line 840, in evaluate
    rval = self.fn(pyll_rval)
  File "/home/peachy/Documents/tensorflow/temp_model.py", line 101, in keras_fmin_fnct
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/peachy/Documents/tensorflow/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/pyll_utils.py", line 21, in wrapper
    raise TypeError('require string label')
TypeError: require string label
```

Solution 3 by merging a list results in the error below which says that %s has been based through along with dropout_1 into the temp_model file which is generated.

```
Unexpected error: <class 'SyntaxError'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hy.py", line 107, in <module>
    trials=Trials())
  File "/home/peachy/Documents/tensorflow/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperas-0.4-py3.6.egg/hyperas/optim.py", line 67, in minimize
    verbose=verbose)
  File "/home/peachy/Documents/tensorflow/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperas-0.4-py3.6.egg/hyperas/optim.py", line 104, in base_minimizer
    from temp_model import keras_fmin_fnct, get_space
  File "/home/peachy/Documents/tensorflow/temp_model.py", line 133
    'Dropout_1': hp.uniform('Dropout_1', %s),
                                         ^
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
model.add(Dropout({{uniform(dropout)}}))
```

The variable `dropout` is defined within the scope of your `model()` function, but within the double brackets `{{ }}`, you have an entirely different scope that is handled by the hyperas library. Hence, the error you're getting is occurring from hyperas, when it attempts to get the space over which to apply this hyper-optimizer:

```
File "/home/peachy/Documents/tensorflow/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperas-0.4-py3.6.egg/hyperas/optim.py", line 118, in base_minimizer
space=get_space(),
File "/home/peachy/Documents/tensorflow/temp_model.py", line 119, in get_space
NameError: name 'dropout' is not defined
```

The variable dropout is not defined within the scope of hyperas (the scope inside `{{ }}`). It is only defined within the scope of the `model()` function.

You'll note that in all of the examples provided in the [hyperas README.md](https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas), the values passed to the hyper-optimizer are hardcoded strings or numbers.

#### Solution 1

If you need to vary these arguments, you can use [eval](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#eval) with the parameters as arguments. For example, to fix the problematic line above and use a variable lower/upper bound on your dropout:

```
lo = 0.2
hi = 0.8
cmd = "model.add(Dropout({{uniform(%.1f,%.1f)}}))"%( lo, hi )
eval(cmd)
```

#### Solution 2

Alternatively, use `.format()` (with two brackets for each one bracket you want in the final string, total of 4):

```
lo = 0.2
hi = 0.8
cmd = "model.add(Dropout({{{{uniform({:.1f},{:.1f})}}}}))".format(lo,hi)
eval(cmd)
```

#### Solution 3

If you have `lo` and `hi` in a list, use `.join()` to combine them into a string and pass them to the `eval()` function:

```
mylist = [0.2, 0.8]
argstring = ",".join( str(x) for x in mylist )
cmd = "model.add(Dropout({{uniform(%s)}}))"%(argstring)
eval(cmd)
```

**EDIT 1:** Added two additional examples - one alternative string formatting function, and one list example.

**EDIT 2:** Separated the string formatting step from the `eval()` step.

Comment: would it be possible to modify the library to accept a list or is that more effort than it's worth ?

Comment: Modifying hyperas to accept variables inside the `{{ }}` templates would be *way* more work than using eval. Remember, we're talking about two completely different scopes that don't know about each other. Using eval is just a matter of string manipulation.

Comment: So is it impossible to feed in a list like this
     eval("model.add(Dropout({{uniform(%.1f)}}))"%( dropout ))

Comment: Also your solutiion throws an error in python 3 not sure if your using python 2 syntax

Comment: This is Python 3 syntax - the documentation I linked to is Python 3 documentation. You can replace "eval()" with "print()" to test out what's going wrong (the eval statement above works in Python 3.5). If you need to print multiple arguments from a list, it's just string manipulation - you can use a list comprehension or a `",".join(mylist)` to assemble your arguments into a single string, then use eval with a `%s` instead of a `%d` or `%f`.

Comment: See updated answer for an alternative string formatting method and a way to pack up lists.

Comment: Check updated question for results of your suggestions

Comment: For debugging, try making a string that hard-codes numbers and run it with eval() to ensure you can call hyperas correctly using eval. If that works, use the string formatting methods to create your string, and assign it to a variable *before* passing it to eval.

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted so that others know what answer/information was useful. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)